# How to add Custom Control in Window?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip, popupwindow

I am in need of showing the custom control inside a NativeWindow as a PopUp when hovering the controls like ToolTip.

I have created the custom control and i could not insert the custom control inside the Window.

Could anyone please share me how to add the custom control in Window as a Popup?

Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: What is *"NativeWindow"* ? It should be possible to create popup window in winforms (`WindowStyles.WS_POPUP`) and it should be possible to add controls to it either in designer or during run-time. So what is the difficulty?

Comment: You can override tooltip's onDraw method if you are after a tooltip.